# How to update with $arrayFilters for array variable value in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

By using arrayFilters, I need to update a collection with dynamic values from an array.

This is to say that, I need to update with array values in $inc, based on the array which is supplied in the arrayFilters.

**SAMPLE DOCUMENT**

```
{
  _id:'shopId',
  products:[
    _id:'productId',
    buys:[
     {
      _id:'abc',
      quantity:0
     },
     {
     _id:'def',
     quantity:2
     }
   ]
 ]
}
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
{
  _id:'shopId',
  products:[
    _id:'productId',
    buys:[
     {
      _id:'abc',
      quantity:1 //got incremented by 1
     },
     {
     _id:'def',
     quantity:5 //got incremented by 3
     }
   ]
 ]
}
```

**Consider this query here below for what I have tried**

```
Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": ObjectId(shopId)},
    { $inc: { "products.$[p].buys.$[n].quantity": { $each: [1,3] } }},              
    { arrayFilters: [{ "p._id": ObjectId('productId') }, { "n._id": {$in: ["abc", "def"]} }]
)
```

I need the *n._id:'abc'* to be incremented by 1 and *n._id:'def'* to be incremented by 3 which are put in an array (*in that $each in $inc*).

Now this doesn't work and gives out an error. I have tried replacing $each:[1,3] with $in: [1,3] but still doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would help to better understand if you provide a sample document and expected result.

Comment: @thammada I have updated my question to include sample document and the expected result

Comment: I think it should be run as 2 separate operations, is it an issue for you to run them separately?

Comment: @thammada Yes, I dont want them separate.. I need them in a single operation. Since it is possible to update with same value, I need a way to update them with different values in that array ie that `[1,3]`

Comment: What do you mean by "Since it is possible to update with same value"? I still think you can separate them into 2 operations, one that matches `"abc"` the other that matches `"def"`. If you want to do it in the same operation it would involve an update pipeline using `$map`, which I think is a lot more complicated

Comment: @thammada  When I say "It is possible to update with same value" I mean this => `{ $inc: { "products.$[p].buys.$[n].quantity": 7 }},` Setting both of them with same value. Meaning that all _ids 'abc' and 'def' will have value 7.

But what I want is them to have different values based on that array supplied ie [1,3]

Comment: I think separate updates should still cover your concerned issue, please check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of MongoDB v4.2 it's not possible to do this with `arrayFilters` in a single operation.

I suggest updating them separately.

```js
// Solution implemented in node.js since, you have tagged mongoose
// prepare condition data structure to use in multiple updates
const updateCondition = { "abc": 1, "def": 3 }

const updates = Object.entries(updateCondition).map(([key, value]) =>
  Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: ObjectId(shopId)} ,
    { $inc: { "products.$[p].buys.$[n].quantity": value } }, // value will be iterated through [1, 3]       
    { arrayFilters: [{ "p._id": ObjectId(productId) }, { "n._id": key } }] // key will be iterated through ["abc", "def"]
  ).exec()
)

await Promise.all(updates).then(([resultA, resultB]) => {
  // resultA is the result of "abc" update
  // resultB is the result of "def" update
}).catch(err => {
  // handle err
})
```

Comment: With the code above, how can I use `.exec() .then(() => .catch(() =>)` with it?

Comment: I have updated the code, you can also handle .then() separately at `.exec().then()`